# Webpage using Rendered Local Font instead of @import

Tags: html, css, sass, fonts, font-face

I run several work webpages that are all around other countries and I am having some issues with a Seoul, South Korean webpage and the fonts that it's applying.

**What I'm trying to achieve**:
I want to have the 'Nanum Gothic' (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nanum+Gothic) font applied on the Korean webpage but instead it's being overwritten by the Malgun Gothic local file.

**Problem**:
*Windows*: When I visit the webpage on Windows, it shows that it's rendering the Malgun Gothic font, but on the CSS its showing that Nanum Gothic is applied with font-family:
[image]
[image]

Below, I will provide all the code references that I currently have:

**variables.scss**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/nanumgothic.css);

// Korean font family based on local team request
$korean: $whitney, 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
```

**_base.scss**:

```
/**
 * Font family for Korean site
 */
html[lang="ko-KR"] body {
    font-family: $korean;
    @include headings {
        font-family: $korean;
    };
}
```

Comment: instead of cdn link you try hosting font in your project and let see what happen.

Comment: @SumitPatel, unfortunately, the way that I have it all setup is that it's only being called in via import and thats all that the corporation allows due copyright reasons.

Answer (score 0):

try using a new font face in your CSS file

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face